# Adding Angular component to Eclipse project

Tags: angular, typescript, eclipse

I have developed an Angular component using `ng new <application_name` and now want to import the code for the component into my Eclipse workspace and make it part of my Web application, which has an Angular JS front-end and a Java back-end accessible via a RESTful interface.  Which files from the project will I need in order to have the code work properly?

Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Comment: Is what you call an "Angular component" is an "Angular project"? Because `ng new <application_name>` creates a new project, not a new component.

Comment: Sorry!  Yes, I created an application and then a component within that application using ng new component <component_name>; it is this component that I would like to add to my Eclipse project so that I can start migrating our application over to pure Angular 14.